# Mongoose update array value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

How to update array value in mongoose ?

This is my schema

```
var cars = new Schema({
    brand : String,
    prices:[ {color : String, price: String}]
}





   let carID = req.body.carID;
   let brandPriceArraySingleID = req.body.brandPriceArraySingleID;
    
    var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
    var query = { 'prices.id' : new ObjectId(brandPriceArraySingleID) };
    
    let carsPriceUpdate = await cars.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { "price": "new price" } });
```

This above code is not working!!

Questions

1. How to find and update array value?
2. Do I need to check whether exist carID in cars model before array value find?

Comment: What is the value for `brandPriceArraySingleID` and what do you want to update? All prices? An specific price for a color in a brand?

Comment: thats object ID

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the Array fields element from the query, you need to use `$` in the field, ex : `{ "prices.$.price": "new price" }`

Try this code.

```
   const query = {
     _id : req.body.carID,
     "prices._id" : req.body.brandPriceArraySingleID
    }

  let carsPriceUpdate = await cars.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $set: { "prices.$.price": "new price" },{ returnDocument: 'after' }});

   console.log(carsPriceUpdate)
```

1. You need to set new value for the object's property ( $ reflects the position).
2. `{ returnDocument: 'after' }` is options of query. it's return document after updating.